# What "64 bit" means?

Tags: 64-bit

I know this question seems obvious, but I don't manage to find a **precise** answer.

If on my laptop it is written "Windows 8 64 bit", what "64 bit" **exactly** refers to? (I know that "Windows 8" is just the name and version of the OS).

I have a few interpretations, but none of them make me entirely happy:

- *The virtual address space of a process is of size 2^64 units (with unit being some small size).* This definition does not make me happy, because even with disc storage, the total storage of my computer is far less than that. So I would never be able in a program to initialize an array of size 2^64.
- *The registers in memory have a capacity of 64 bits.* This also does not make me entirely happy, because my machine could have **both** 64 bit and 32 bit registers, and perhaps registers of smaller size.
- The maximum capacity of registers is 64 bits. This definition could be sensible, but looks "iffy".

So could anyone give me a clear definition, or at least tell that one of the above is correct?

Comment: 64bit is the CPU's mode first of all, in this mode CPU can address up-to 2^64 bytes, to do this CPU uses 64 bit registers, which is maximal capacity for them in this mode. windows x64 means version of software which requires CPU to support this mode

Comment: also - registers are not in memory, they are in cpu internally, and they could be 128 bit (like xmm ones), but these are not used for memory addressing

Answer (score 0):

1. "Windows 64 bit" means that the *operating system* supports 64-bit addressing.
2. This, in turn, implies that the *CPU* also supports 64-bit addressing.
3. The OS and the CPU are two entirely different things.
4. Runtime binaries (.exes and .dlls for Windows) are yet another "different thing".  32-bit and 64-bit .exe's have different binary formats, are loaded differently by the OS, and use different runtime resources.
5. You can't run a 64-bit OS on a 32-bit CPU.  But you *can* run a 32-bit OS on a 64-bit CPU.  Similarly, you can't use a 64-bit shared library or executable program on a 32-bit OS.
6. The key aspect of "64-bit" is 64-bit *addressing*: that both the CPU and the running program can address up to 2^64 bytes of virtual memory:
7. In practice, a running program will likely be able to address only a portion of that address space.
8. You can read more here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing

PS:

Yes: CPU registers come in all different sizes.  For example, ah is 8-bits, ax 16 bits, eax 32 bits and rax is 64 bits.  Furthermore, different registers do "different things".  For "64-bit computing", we're primarily interested in those registers that load from and store to virtual memory.

Comment: Although I would imagine the OP has an Intel processor, this answer is very specific to _amd64_. Many 64 bit processors can't natively run 32 bit programs. You either have to recompile (and hope they work) in 64 bit or have an interpreter (which means it'd probably be really slow.) Also most 32 and 64 bit processors do not offer to access registers in 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits. In most cases, the registers are always viewed as 64 bit except to access memory (load/store).